# Problemas con un ciclo que da el error "Notice: Undefined variable"

Tags: php

Estoy haciendo una galeria dinamica con PHP y MySQL, pero a la hora de hacer un ciclo me da estos dos errores

> Notice: Undefined variable: fotos in
> C:\xammp2\htdocs\curso_PHP\practicas\galeria_dinamica\views\index.view.php
> on line 18
>
> Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in
> C:\xammp2\htdocs\curso_PHP\practicas\galeria_dinamica\views\index.view.php
> on line 18"

Aquí esta el código del ciclo:

```html
<?php foreach($fotos as $foto): ?>
           <div class="thumb">
             <a href="foto.php?id=<?php echo $foto['id']; ?>">
               <img src="fotos/<?php echo $foto['imagen'] ?>" alt="">
             </a>
           </div>
         <?php endforeach;?>
```

Ya declare la variable en el documento index.php, y siempre habia hecho los ciclos de esta manera

Comment: Mejor coloca el código para ver todo el panorama y poder ver, por ejemplo, qué dice la línea 18 que genera el error de la imagen.

Comment: Parece un problema al declarar la variable, puedes mostrarnos esa parte del código?

Comment: Añade también el código donde defines la variable fotos.

Comment: Comentaste que la variable está definida en `index.php`, pero el archivo que estás ejecutando es `index.view.php`... ¿deberías incluir a index dentro de este? ¿o cómo pensabas que la variable de un script se acceda desde otro?

Answer (score 1):

El mensaje indica el problema:

1) la variable $fotos no esta definida:

> Notice: Undefined variable: fotos in

2) ya que $fotos no esta definida el [foreach()](http://php.net/manual/es/control-structures.foreach.php) envía este mensaje:

> Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in

Esto se debe a que [foreach()](http://php.net/manual/es/control-structures.foreach.php) necesita un array y un objeto.

**Asegura definir $fotos y que sea un array.**

---

puedes validar antes de realizar el [foreach()](http://php.net/manual/es/control-structures.foreach.php) que los valores que necesita sean correctos mediante:

```
if (is_array($fotos) || is_object($foto)){
 //Realiza foreach()
}
```